# Why Image file path not working in bootstrap?

Tags: html

My Folder directories are as described below

Root Directory: `G:/bootstrap/index.html`

Image directory: `G:/sample.jpg`

I wanted to link my image like this. But image path is not working properly. I have added Bootstrap CDN in head section.

But browser is not showing image properly. What may be the reason.

Comment: Please add some code to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: it would be nice to see some code to really understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

Browsers aren't allowed to access local file in the format you are trying. Rather access the file like this: `file://G:/sample.jpg`